# What are Dashworlds.com domain names

Tags: internet, dns, domain-name

I have just seen [Dash Worlds Domain Names](http://dashworlds.com) and I was wondering how do they work. They claim that you can register a free domain like `example-com` (not `example.com`) and then you download a plugin that you can display all dash-com domain names. How is this possible? Can anybody on the internet access these sites, or only if they have the plugin installed?

Comment: See [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/how-can-i-buy-my-own-personalized-top-level-domain-tld) and [this Wikipedia entry on Alternate DNS Root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_DNS_root).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This service looks *highly* questionable. I don't know the internals of how it's working, as they don't entirely reveal it, and use a lot of buzzwords like "Private Networking Technology", but here is my best understanding:

- You "register" a domain like `superuser-com` with them
- They add `superuser-com` to a database, but do not actually register any real DNS domain
- When you install their plugin, it looks at the domain you enter. If it is in their database of "dash" domains, then they return the IP address that corresponds with it. So, if you type in `superuser-com`, the plugin would look in their database, then send the browser to the Super User website, but it would appear that you were going to `superuser-com`.

There are numerous downsides to this. First of all, if you do not have their browser plugin, you cannot visit the site. This cuts off 99.9999999999% of the internet. Their sites also do not currently show up in Google searches, and when they do, it will probably be through sketchy means:

> **Will my domain name appear on Google?**
>
> We are currently setting up a system for spidering these sites on Google. Users will be advised when the system is ready by a newsletter.
>
> Keep your e-mail of registrations always working to receive the DASHWORLDS newsletter.

As a website creator, you would be **foolish** to use this service. Forcing visitors to install sketchy browser plugins, using a service which does *not* use standard DNS to resolve sites, and their completely unclear pricing policies are all reasons that I would be wary at the least. While the product likely does what they claim, you would be much, *much* better just registering your own regular domain with a reputable registrar.

Comment: +1 much better, clearer answer than mine, deleting mine

Comment: Thanks @Sathya. Feel free to edit my answer to include any additional info you think might be relevant.